# Finding the Arithmetic Mean of an Array: C#

Tags: c#, arrays, math, mean

Language: C#

I have an array of numbers that the user entered, and I want to find the arithmetic mean of the array.

I looked up a couple of similiar cases, but couldn't really find anything I was looking for... Anyway, here is the code:

```
            Console.WriteLine("\n How many numbers do you want to average? \n");

            int nNumtoAvg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            int[] nListToAverage = new int[nNumtoAvg];



            for (int i = 0; i < nNumtoAvg; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter whole number #" + (i + 1) + ": ");

                string sVal = Console.ReadLine();

                int nValue = Convert.ToInt32(sVal);

                nListToAverage[i] = nValue;

            }
```

Now, what would I do to add all the numbers in the array together, and then divide that by the array.Length? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Yes, you add them and divide by length. Exactly like you would do that manually on a piece of paper.

Comment: `I looked up a couple of similiar cases, but couldn't really find anything I was looking for` You are the first one to solve this problem in all computer history :)

Comment: Yes, but how would I add them is what I'm wondering...

Comment: Well, you add 2 integers with `+` operator. `sum = a + b;`

Comment: Well obviously, if we were adding two consecutive numbers, but this is an array...

Comment: `sum = sum + nValue;`  Or learn about `+=`

Comment: With array it's exactly the same - you iterate over it and add the numbers using `+`.

Comment: You are allowed to keep values in other variables. E.g. a running sum.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this many ways but I would do the following after your for loop.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nNumtoAvg; i++)
     sum += nListToAverage[i];

int result = sum / nNumtoAvg;   // result now has the average of those numbers.
```

You could also do it in the for loop you already have but it wont really make a difference in complexity if you don't have very much numbers to input.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an int as the result, how about:

```
int average = Convert.ToInt32(nListToAverage.Average());
```

Otherwise, you get a more precise answer with a double:

```
double average = nListToAverage.Average();
```

If you *need* to add all the items first, you can also do:

```
int average = nListToAverage.Sum() / nListToAverage.Length;
```

Or the old-school, show-your-work way:

```
int sum = 0;
int average = 0;
int numItems = nListToAverage.Length;

if (numItems > 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
    {
        sum += nListToAverage[i];
    }

    average = sum / numItems;
}
```